# Ограничить фоновые данные програмно Android

Tags: android, java

Как включить ограничение фоновых данных программно?

Comment: Кругом вопросы: что за данные? Какой фон имеется ввиду? Переформулируйте вопрос более точно и конкретно

Comment: Просто кто сидит на андроиде наверное понял.
Фоновые данные, имеется ввиду получение данных через мобильный интернет в фоновом режиме.

Comment: кто сидит в андроиде - не кто и не чего не понял. :) по простому ты хочешь сделать фаервол?

Comment: http://s4.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2012/11/23d2dbbc25a0dd7d28b6cfad1ada0506.png
http://s4.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2012/11/49c2c956802b4792999173ed46e892c6.png

Вот это я имею ввиду..

Comment: Гугль подсказывает, что это нельзя сделать программно.  

[android api set mobile data limit]( http://www.google.com/m?q=android%20api%20set%20mobile%20data%20limit&client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new)

Comment: @inc
>Просто кто сидит на андроиде наверное понял.

поменьше апломба и крутизны, а то ведь народ и обидеться может...

Answer (score 1):

это фаервол - это можно сделать, но лучше взять уже готовые программы. доступ к телефону должен быть рутирован

Comment: Например, такая функция есть у [Avast! Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity). Только для этого телефон должен быть рутован, тогда можно для каждой аппы (или для всех скопом) установить запрет на выход в сеть.